# Decode base64 array at specific index positions

Tags: python, base64

I handle a big number of XML files, each of which stores a float64 array in the form of a base64 string.
For each of these files, I would like to access the value of its array at a specific index without loading the whole array. I wish to do this in Python.

Currently, I decode the entire string and then access the value at given index, but I am looking for a much faster method.

Comment: 1. Is your base64-encoded array is a single-string only (i.e. no spaces/eols)?
2. What's the size of a float?

Comment: 1. Yes, it's a single 1-million-character-long string. 2. Sorry, I don't know what you mean

Comment: I mean, float64 - what's size of it in bytes (most likely 8...)? As I understand it is stored in binary format, 'as it is', not converted to the string or anything other.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand, each float uses 8 bytes to store. Each 3-bytes of binary data are mapped to 4 base64 chars. So, in order to access i-th float, you'll need to:

- get base64 chars from index `(i * 8 / 3) * 4` to `(i * 8) / 3) * 4 + 4`
- decode that chunk from base64 to binary
- drop first `(i * 8) % 3` bytes
- use next 8 bytes as a float64 value.

Comment: I see what you are trying to do. However, `n * 8 / 3 * 4` (where `n` is the length of my number array) does not equal the number of characters in the base64 string (relative error is about 3%). Also, I just checked several files: even though the encoded array length is the same across files, the base64 string length is different (relative variation is about 1%), so I don't think this technique can work.

Comment: If n is not multiple of 3 then 1 or 2 bytes of padding are added, you may notice them with `=` or `==` at the end of the stream. Yeah, that would require some edge-case checks.

Comment: There is indeed some padding, but it can't account for all the gap between the two values. Here are some examples: I opened 3 files, each of which encodes a 10242-long float64 array ; their base64 strings are respectively 105248, 105720 and 106060-character long.
Also, I read that 1 float64 is 8 bytes, there are 8 bits by byte and there are 6 bits by base64 character, which indeed yields the same formula as you. However, the previous strings' length should be around 10242 * 8 * 8 / 6 = 109248

Comment: Then should be something wrong with underlying binary representation (some additional data, compression, whatsoever) or non-base64 encoding is used, like base58. Base64 strictly maps 3 bytes to 4 chars, plus 1-2 additional chars for input which is not aligned by 3 bytes.